# Cannot use the Cloud Datastore Emulator because the packaged grpcio is incompatible

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

Cannot use the Cloud Datastore Emulator because the packaged grpcio is incompatible to this system. Please install grpcio using pip. i have install it but still give the error. i run the project on dev container

Comment: Maybe you should install it with Python2 because dev_server runs on Python2